# How to select itemclick event for listview with multiple rows in android?

Tags: android, web-services, listview, adapter, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to get values from server and retrieved response from server, the details responsed from server are need to be displayed in a listview, i achieved that too, but while onitemclick process only first row in list view performs the click action but it is not performing for the remaining rows, how can i achieve it, dat is whatever the row and item i'm selecting it has to be processed by my code, here is my code for the reference,     .........

```
    public void userInterface() throws JSONException 
    {
        if(json_user.get(0) != null)
        {
            downloadList1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvinbox);
            populateData();
            downloadList1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    fma=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.src);
                    st=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sub);
                    fma.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                            String fm=fma.getText().toString();
                            String s=st.getText().toString();
                            Intent m = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InActivity.class);
                            m.putExtra("f", fm);
                            m.putExtra("s", s);
                            startActivity(m);
                        }
                    });
                st.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String fm=fma.getText().toString();
                            String s=st.getText().toString();
                            Intent m = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InActivity.class);
                            m.putExtra("f", fm);
                            m.putExtra("s", s);
                            startActivity(m);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Empty",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            Intent menu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenActivity.class);
            menu.putExtra("username", dest);
            startActivity(menu);
        }
    }
    public void populateData() throws JSONException 
    {
        resultVector = new Vector<ListDataItemInbox>();


        int len = json_user.length();
        System.out.println("length--------------------->"+len);
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            JSONObject obj=json_user.getJSONObject(i);

            listData = new ListDataItemInbox();
            listData.sets(obj.getString(KEY_S));
            listData.setd(obj.getString(KEY_D));
            resultVector.add(listData);

            myHandler.post(myRunnable);

        }
    }
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            customListAdapter = new ListViewAdapterInbox(InActivity.this);
            customListAdapter.setResultsData(resultVector);
            downloadList1.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
        }
    };
```

Comment: try to put you textView ClickListener in getview Method of ListViewAdapterInbox

Comment: there is no need to onclick in OnItemClickListner

Comment: Hello Deepaner! i tried like you said, it works but even i selecting second row it displays first row again.. how can i get that particular row here.... help me plz....

Comment: only first row gets selected, all remaining rows are not getting selected, if i'm trying to select other rows it doesnt do any actions why? can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.
make the ArrayList in list adapter class

```
ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and create this method also in that same class.

```
public void toggleSelected(Integer position){
            selectedIds.clear();
            selectedIds.add(position);
        }
```

Now whenever you click on any item of listview pass that item position to this method. And inside your getView method set the check before setting the text. something like this..

```
if (selectedIds.contains(position)){
                  ----- your code ----
              }else{
                 ----- your code ----
              }
```

it perform the operation only on selected position . Try it.!

Comment: only first row gets selected, all remaining rows are not getting selected, if i'm trying to select other rows it doesnt do any actions why? can anybody help me?

Comment: did anybody have suggestion for my question?